# Linking a URL to text using Google script in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a URL ready to be followed. I am sending an email using Google script, and in this email I need this link to be there but I do not want it to be:

http://example.com/this/is/very/ugly/when/it/comes/to/sending/emails

I would like it to be `Example`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send HTML email to do that.

In Google Apps Script you do that by specifying a `htmlBody` element to the `MailApp.sendMessage` method:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
 to: "recipient@example.com",
 subject: "Your link",
 htmlBody: "Here is your example link: " +
           "<a href=\"http://example.com/this/is/very/ugly/when/it/comes/to/sending/emails\">Example</a>"
});
```

See the documentation for [MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)).